# Rolling 24 Hour Flagging in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, rolling-computation

I am trying to calculate a rolling 24H based on the sum of the column labeled "CHI" and the threshold is 34,383. I need to be able to find if any value exceeds the threshold and flags the next data points that included in that 24 hour period.

The image below has a start time, which is column C and also my time reference. CHI, column E, is the value I am summing and then comparing to the target threshold, 64,383. I have a formula that can calculate the next 24 hours from that outage reference, but there can be multiple subsequent rows items that exceed the threshold. From the reference of the standard my industry uses, I am not allowed to flag rows outside of the 24 hour period. So I need to find the MAX rolling 24-hour sum and then flag all items 24 hours after that max value. Another trick is that you can more than one of these MAX thresholds broken in a single week and I would like to still capture those thresholds.

Formula to calculate 24 hours:

=SUMIFS($E$3:$E$243,$C$3:$C$243,">="&C3,$C$3:$C$243,"<"&C3+1)

The image shows a sample of the data I am trying to use.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZhzT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, actual data, rather than an image, and actual column IDs would be better that what you are showing here, but I think it should be something like this.

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(A$1,(ROWS(C$1:C1)-1)*24,0,24))
```

Change the ranges to suit your needs (I can't tell what columns you are actually using here).

Comment: Well due to company restrictions I am not able to access/post the data to common file drop sites. Please see the edit to the post for additional info.